# How do I get my flextable to retain the names of elements in the list that it draws from in R?

Tags: r, loops, flextable

My flextable function keeps replacing the element names of table_list with "var1", "var2" etc. I don't want that.

Here is my data:

```
table_list<-list(A03.PREDIABETES = structure(list(Var1 = structure(1:2, levels = c("N", 
"Y"), class = "factor"), Freq = c(8L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L)), A03.GOITER = structure(list(Var1 = structure(1L, levels = "N", class = "factor"), 
    Freq = 11L), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L)), 
    A03.GESTATIONAL = structure(list(Var1 = structure(1:2, levels = c("N", 
    "Y"), class = "factor"), Freq = c(9L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -2L)), A03.HASHIMOTO = structure(list(Var1 = structure(1L, levels = "N", class = "factor"), 
        Freq = 11L), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -1L)), A03.THYROID = structure(list(Var1 = structure(1:2, levels = c("N", 
    "Y"), class = "factor"), Freq = c(10L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -2L)), A03.HYPERTHYROID = structure(list(Var1 = structure(1:2, levels = c("N", 
    "Y"), class = "factor"), Freq = c(10L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -2L)), A03.HYPOTHYROID = structure(list(Var1 = structure(1L, levels = "N", class = "factor"), 
        Freq = 11L), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -1L)), A03.OTHER = structure(list(Var1 = structure(1:2, levels = c("N", 
    "Y"), class = "factor"), Freq = c(10L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -2L)), A03.NONE = structure(list(Var1 = structure(1:2, levels = c("N", 
    "Y"), class = "factor"), Freq = c(7L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -2L)))
```

Here is my code:

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(writexl)
library(anytime)
library(officer)
library(flextable)

# Create a Word document
doc <- read_docx()

# Add each table to the Word document
for (i in 1:length(table_list)) {
  df <- table_list[[i]]
  table <- flextable(df)
  table <- set_table_properties(table, width = .5)
  doc <- doc %>% body_add_flextable(table)
}

# Save the Word document
print(doc, target = "report.docx")
```

Specifically, the labels are lost here:
for (i in 1:length(table_list)) {
df <- table_list[[i]]
I think it has to do with the loop accessing things through numbers rather than names.
I've tried iterating over things using element names. But if that is the solution, I haven't figured out how to do it correctly.

Comment: How is your `baseline` data frame defined?

Comment: The columns have the labels I want to apply. But when things are converted to a list, the elements lose the names and take on generic names. I successfully reapply the names here: table_list<-setNames(table_list, labels$V1). However, they are lost again in  this part: for (i in 1:length(table_list)) {
  df <- table_list[[i]].  Or are you asking for the data? I get get you a dput summary of it if that is what you are asking.

Comment: Yes, I was asking for a dput summary. without it I can't run your code. Also it would be helpful if you could add your desired output to your question

Comment: Your code at this point does not show any changes you've made to the variable labels in each data frame of `table_list`. You're only converting each data frame into a flextable object and saving it in a word document without any modification of the labels like you mentioned in your question. I would highly recommend reading this post [how to create a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/16421247)

Comment: Perhaps the issue is how I am talking about it. I have now removed some of my code that I had provided only for context sake and have also added in libraries. The problem DOES exist in the code that is provided though. The elements had names in the dput I provided (i.e. "A03.GESTATIONAL". They get removed in these lines: for (i in 1:length(table_list)) {
  df <- table_list[[i]].

Comment: the word document just says var1, var2, etc. rather than including the names of the elements. I think it has to do with the looping iterating based on element number, rather than element name. I tried running things with iterating on the element name, but the code didn't work. I have also tried re-assigning the names after the loop, but I couldn't get that to work either, The code should run as it is. I was able to run just what I have here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add labels as captions for each table. This can be done using `flextable::set_caption`.

```
library(officer)
library(flextable)

doc <- read_docx()

for(i in 1:length(table_list)){
  tbl <- table_list[[i]] |> 
    flextable() |> 
    set_table_properties(width = 0.5) |> 
    set_caption(names(table_list)[[i]])
  
  doc <- doc |> body_add_flextable(tbl)
}

print(doc, target = "report.docx")
```

output:

[image]

[image]